# How to set max-width in select2 jquery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-select2

I am using this jQuery plugin [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) . All is working properly. But the input type will expand all the way to the bottom if i select plenty. How to make it fix height?

Here is my simple `select2` implementation:

```
$('#profit-centers-hidden-select').select2({
    width: '150px',
    height: '30px', // I tried this or max-height but no luck
    placeholder : 'Select Profit Centers'
});
```

[image: Here is the screen shot, notice that it is the default behaviour of that plugin, but if there's a way to not make it expand/stretch based on the number of data added, that would be great. thanks]

Comment: What do you mean by "input type will expand all the way to the bottom if I select plenty"? Could you add a screenshot for clarification?

Comment: It would be great if you can attach the screen shot of the issue you are facing.